# Multiple input model can't handle input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Trying a 2 input model, one from image generator and one from a dataframe.

```
X_train = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['featureA', 'featureB', 'featureC'])

print('Importing keras...')
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

print('Defining datagens and dataflows...')

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255.,
                                   rotation_range = 25,
                                   width_shift_range = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
                                   height_shift_range = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   channel_shift_range = 0.3,
                                   horizontal_flip = True,
                                   vertical_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )

# Flow training images batch size should consider RAM
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df_train_img,
                                                    directory='/jpeg/train',
                                                    x_col = 'image_name',
                                                    y_col = 'target',
                                                    batch_size = 20,
                                                    class_mode = 'binary', 
                                                    target_size = (256, 256))     

# Flow validation images batch size should consider RAM
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df_test_img,                                                 
                                                    directory='/jpeg/train',
                                                    x_col = 'image_name',
                                                    y_col = 'target',
                                                    batch_size = 20,
                                                    class_mode = 'binary', 
                                                    target_size = (256, 256))

print('Done')

from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
!wget --no-check-certificate \
    https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5 \
    -O /tmp/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5

from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
local_weights_file = '/tmp/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'

pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(input_shape = (256, 256, 3), 
                                include_top = False,
                                weights = None)

pre_trained_model.load_weights(local_weights_file)

pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(input_shape = (256, 256, 3), 
                                include_top = False,
                                weights = None)

reg_model = keras.Sequential([
  layers.Flatten(input_shape=(3, )),
  layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(12, activation='softmax')
])

z = layers.concatenate([img_model.output,reg_model.output])
z = layers.Flatten()(z)
z = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(z)
z = layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)                  
z = layers.Dense  (2, activation='softmax')(z)


model = Model( inputs=[reg_model.input, img_model.input], outputs=z) 

model.compile(optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0001), 
              loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
            [train_generator, X_train], y_train,
            epochs = 20,
            verbose = 2)
```

train_generator is an image generator. If the model has only one input and I pass that I get no errors.
X_train is a pandas Dataframe with 12 columns. (changed to 3 for the reproductable model)

Getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'keras_preprocessing.image.dataframe_iterator.DataFrameIterator'>", "<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>"}), <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

What I tried:

- converting the dataframe to array (np.asarray())
- converting the dataframe to tensor dataset
- testing the 2 models separated with the inputs. Both worked

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Comment: Edited it to include sample inputs